# Custom Design of an Excel Textbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Well I was wondering whether we can somehow create custom looking text boxes that act as an input box and is linked to VBA.

As far as I am aware the standard procedure would entail adding an ActiveX Textbox Control and then using the `TextBox1_Change` event to add the code as to what needs to happen when the user enters something in to.

Sadly the look of the default textbox isn't matching the way I want by spreadsheet to look. So is there any way to change how it looks or have something replace it while serving the same purpose?

One thing I could think of and have tried is inserting a shape (blue):

[Shape http://im52.gulfup.com/qD2F0B.png](http://im52.gulfup.com/qD2F0B.png)

I can get the text that is in the shape using VBA by:

```
InputText = Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

But I don't suppose there is a way to detect a change of shape text event?

Suggestions / Workarounds are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limitations on what you can change on an ActiveX TextBox, such as Font/Color/Border/SpecialEffects, but the basic rectangle shape cannot be changed.

However you can make the TextBox transparent by **BackStyle** property and group it to a shape (bring the TB forward) and still use the `TextBox1_Change` method for changes.

If you need to access the value in the TextBox somewhere else, a quick way is to use `TextBox1.LinkedCell` and below to set the value to a cell, or a Named Range.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ' Same Sheet as TextBox1
    ActiveSheet.Range(TextBox1.LinkedCell).Value = TextBox1.Value
    ' Or Below for Named Range
    ThisWorkbook.Names(TextBox1.LinkedCell).RefersToRange.Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

[image: ActiveX TextBox Properties][image: TxtBox on Top of Shape]